# What is "k-Local Hamiltonian Problem" in quantum complexity theory?

Tags: quantum-information

An example of a QMA problem is the k-LOCAL HAMILTONIAN problem. What exactly is it?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QMA#The_local_Hamiltonian_problem